# How to keep program data in different m files in matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to write a modular matlab program and I have some data structures such as history in my program. Is that true that I have to keep all my data-structures in the main script of my program? In other words if I have some arrays and fields of data, if I put them in other m files, such as functions, they are temporal and they are going to be collected as garbage in my program execution. I am a java developer and now I want to develop some code in matlab.

Comment: @HunterJiang As I know making variables global, causes difficulties in managing the code by the programmer. I want some method to handle data in different classes and files, just like Java.

Comment: Just like you should be doing it in Java... use classes and store data into the properties of their instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Tommaso suggested in a comment, you should use classes. Look at the [documentation for `classdef`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/classdef.html) to get started. The full documentation to create classes [starts at this page](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/object-oriented-programming.html).

But to directly answer your question: it is possible to store static data in functions: [see `persistent`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/persistent.html).

If you're making a GUI, there are built-in ways to store data, see [`guidata`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/guidata.html).

Finally, there is also [`getappdata`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setappdata.html) and `setappdata`, which set global variables but specific to one app.

For all that's good in this world, don't use `global`, it's not worth the hassle, here are plenty of better alternatives.

PS: if the links here break, note that it is always possible to type `help <cmd>` to get help on one of the functions mentioned here.